# GAE Datastore - Reduce Cursor String (base 64) Length

Tags: string, google-app-engine, encoding, google-cloud-datastore

Currently, I'm when passing around a cursor string in a URL, and it looks very ugly. I was wondering if there was a way to shorten these? I was thinking I could encode it & decode it somehow, but I don't really know where to start looking for information on this.

The cursor string is a base 64 encoded string. Any way to shorten it without loosing any data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think there would be an easier way to shorten and again retrieve back the exact string.

I would suggest you to maintain your own mapping of shortened string to original string in the backend preferably using [memcache](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache/overview.html).